# Using pipes inside bash function

Tags: bash

I found myself in the need to create a bash function that can come in handy when executing a detailing listing on a directory with numerous files. As I usually pipe that to less, I thought I might as well create a short function for this.
Here is my function, I can't get it to work. I'm not that sure if I can apply a pipe like this within a function...

```
function kk (){
  ls -l $1 | less;
}
```

I add the function at the bottom of my /etc/bash.bashrc file, and sourced my /etc/bash.bashrc, so that changes would kick in.
But then when I run "kk" on my bash shell, it only does a regular ls, it is missing the pipe to less.

Comment: What's the problem? It works for me

Comment: Works find for me in bash. What is your error message? What does `type kk` output for you? I suspect it's not defined so probably an issue with the environment. If written in a script you have to `source` it and not execute it. That'd be my first few guesses

Comment: @1_CR No, this is on-topic

Comment: 'I can't get it to work.' you'll have to give a better description that that. please edit your question with a sample list of files, and then the output you expect to see using less. It should work. Good luck.

Comment: @hek2mgl, okie-dokes. Close vote retracted seeing that this is likely a non-issue

Comment: @1_CR perhaps. I couldn't reproduce any problem

Comment: I added the function at the bottom of my /etc/bash.bashrc file, and sourced my /etc/bash.bashrc, so that changes would kick in. But then when I run "kk" on my bash shell, it only does a regular ls, it is missing the pipe to less.

Comment: Ok. I finally solved it. It looks like I was under impression that sourcing /etc/bash.bashrc was updating my changes, but they only came in after I did a logout/login.

Comment: Pls add votes to comments that were helpful. Thanks.